# How to add an action a JQuery mobile Collapsible header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

In my Collapsible header I am trying to append an extra anchor tag which is pushed away from the header because this is not supported for JQuery mobile headers. Is there a way to add an extra link/action to the heading of a Collapsible in a neath way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject a button inside the collapsible from the `$(document).on("collapsiblecreate")` event, but I prefer to use *pre-enhanced* markup as described [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/collapsible/) (this should improve performance during page creation).

Here is an example (I believe everybody who is using JQM had such a problem at least one time...)

So, basically, instead of relying completely to the `data-role` enhancement, You need to write in Your `html` the expanded markup and the classes which JQM would add later during the widget initialization. To tell JQM that the markup is *pre-enhanced* add the `data-enhanced="true"` data-attribute to the widget.

This way, You are free to add whichever element You want inside any widget (`search-inputs`  & so on). Just look inside the chrome developer tools: mostly, You will only need to copy-and-paste the markup enhanced by JQM using its own standard method and use that in Your `html` page.

```js
$(document).on("collapsiblecreate", ".ui-collapsible", function(e) {
  /* $(this) is the collapsible */
});
```

```css
.collapsible-assist {
  position: relative;
}

.collapsible-assist .ui-collapsible-heading {
  margin-right: 2.5em;
}

.collapsible-assist.square .ui-collapsible-heading {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.collapsible-assist .assist-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.collapsible-assist.square .assist-btn {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: inherit;
  border-top-right-radius: inherit;
}

.collapsible-assist .ui-collapsible-content {
  margin-top: -1px !important;
  border-top-width: 1px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: inherit;
}


/* JQM no frills */

.ui-btn,
.ui-btn:hover,
.ui-btn:focus,
.ui-btn:active,
.ui-btn:visited {
  text-shadow: none !important;
}

.ui-btn:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}


/* Speed-up some android & iOS devices */

* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-enhanced="true" class="collapsible-assist square ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-collapsed">
        <a href="#popup" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="assist-btn ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-info">Help</a>
        <h4 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-plus">Farm animals<div class="ui-collapsible-heading-status">click to expand contents</div></a></h4>
        <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
          <ul data-role="listview" data-enhanced="false">
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Chicken</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Cow</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Duck</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-enhanced="true" class="collapsible-assist round ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-collapsed">
        <a href="#popup" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="assist-btn ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-icon-info">Help</a>
        <h4 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-plus">Legend<div class="ui-collapsible-heading-status">click to expand contents</div></a></h4>
        <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
          <form>
            <div data-role="controlgroup">
              <input name="checkbox-1-a" id="checkbox-1-a" type="checkbox" checked>
              <label for="checkbox-1-a">One</label>
              <input name="checkbox-2-a" id="checkbox-2-a" type="checkbox">
              <label for="checkbox-2-a">Two</label>
              <input name="checkbox-3-a" id="checkbox-3-a" type="checkbox">
              <label for="checkbox-3-a">Three</label>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popup" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
      <p>I'm a help popup.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```